# Error TypeError: this is undefined al realizar una validación asíncrona con angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, validación, programacion-asincrona

Estoy realizando con Angular 10 una validación asíncrona para ver si un usuario existe ya en la base de datos y, en ese caso, devolver un mensaje de error indicando que el usuario no está disponible.

Pero cuando me pongo a teclear el usuario me salta el siguiente error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this is undefined
    usuarioExiste alta-usuario.component.ts:177
    ZoneAwarePromise Angular
    usuarioExiste alta-usuario.component.ts:175
    Angular 38
    AltaUsuarioComponent_Template alta-usuario.component.html:13
    Angular 13
    RxJS 72
```

He revisado mi código y no veo nada raro. ¿Me podríais decir por qué se está produciendo este error?

- Forma de declarar mi validación:

```
formAlta = this.formBuilder.group({
      usuario: ['', , this.usuarioExiste],
      contrasena: ['', Validators.required],
      contrasena2: ['', Validators.required],
```

- Método que tiene la validación:

```
interface ErrorValidate {
  [s:string]: boolean
}

 /* Validaciones asíncronas: Verifica que el usuario no exista en la BBDD */
  usuarioExiste(control: FormControl): Promise<ErrorValidate> {

    if(!control.value) {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    }

    return new Promise( resolve => {
      // Llamamos al backend para ver si existe el usuario
      this.auth.buscarUsuario(control.value).subscribe(
          resp => {
            // Devolvemos el error
            resolve({existe: true})
          },
          error => {
            // La validación pasa correctamente
            resolve(null)
          });            
    });
  }
```

- Método con el servicio invocado al servicio REST:

```
buscarUsuario(usuario: string): Observable<any>{
     return this.http.get(`${environment.url}/usuarios/${usuario}`);
  }
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se puede leer en el mensaje el error esta al llamar al validador "this.usuarioExiste" que he de suponer que lo tendrás en forma de servicio, angular te dice que dicho servicio es undefined,
Asegúrate de haberlo importado bien en el constructor y de pasarle un formControl cuando llames al validador ya que dicha función requiere de uno.

Comment: tengo el validador en el mismo servicio que el otro codigo

Comment: Hola. Debugueando he visto que el problema está en que si hago un console.log de this es undefined, es decir el this ha perdido su referencia al metodo post y no llega a hacer la llamada this.auth.buscarUsuario(control.value).subscribe

Comment: ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? He intentado de todo, he googleado y no encuentro como solucionar este problema. El this ya me llega como undefined nada más entrar en el método, he intentado pasarle una referencia a this desde fuera y nada

Comment: Para que no se pierda el this declara tu método como buscarUsuario = (usuario: string): Observable<any> => {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.url}/usuarios/${usuario}`);
}